# What is the equivalent to pip -t in setup.py?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

Does the setuptools library have an equivalent function to a pip targeted dependency install?
Example:

```
pip -t lib my_cool_libary
```

The above example would install `my_cool_library` in the local folder "lib".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setup.py supports command line flags that you can use to set the prefix directory for installs.

https://docs.python.org/2.0/inst/custom-install.html

Comment: That would work if I knew the path ahead of time, but sometimes I'll only know the location of the setup.py file.  I'd like to define the lib path inside the setup.py file.

Comment: Looking again, I think that article points out I can do that in the distils config file... I'll accept the answer if I can ultimately make that work.

Comment: So you are trying to make someone else to install the library into a location you define?

Comment: Short answer - yes. Long answer - the intended install is a targeted install for a Google app engine install.  So Id like to be able to commit the code to a repository, but please a setup file that installs the required libs to a particular folder.

Comment: I see. The vendoring part of app engine is a pain at first.